# eigen value decomposition of co-variance a series generated by factor model

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, matrix-decomposition

Let's assume $N\times T$ series $Y_t$ is generated by the following equation.
$$ Y_t = \begin{bmatrix}A_x &  A_m\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_t \\ m_t \end{bmatrix}$$
Where $A_x$ and $A_m$ are $N\times 1$ matrix and 
$x_t$ and $m_t$ are $1\times T$ series and 
$$ Cov\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_t \\ m_t \end{bmatrix}\right)= \begin{bmatrix}\sigma_x^2 & 0 \\
 0& \sigma_m^2\end{bmatrix}$$

Can we say anything (expression in terms of $A_x$ , $A_m$ $\sigma_m^2$ and $\sigma_m^2$)   about the eigenvalue and eigenvector of the $Cov(Y_t)$

Comment: One thing you can say is that $\text{cov}(Y_t)$ has rank of at most 2. So it has at most 2 positive eigenvalues, and the rest are exactly 0.

Comment: Yes, but can we not get any expression for these two eigenvalues?